# Speaking Plain HTTP over an SSL enabled Server port

Tags: tls, http, apache

atm I'm facing a problem with IE and Firefox because they don't redirect my Links correctly. 
I'm requesting my application via:

```
https://myapp.example.de/context
```

In my webapplication I have links like that:

```
http://myapp.example.de:443/context/sublink
```

When I try to navigate to this link I get the following error

**in Firefox:**

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

**in IE:**

blank page

**in Chrome:** 
it works perfectly and I'm redirected to the correct path which is:

```
https://myapp.example.de/context/sublink
```

My rewrite condition in my apache vhost from 80 to 443 and 443 looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://myapp.example.com/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost ip:443>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PROTOCOL}  =http
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://myapp.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I write a Apache redirect rule that lets me navigate to this links and redirect them to the correct path which would be:

```
https://myapp.example.de/context/sublink
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

> http://myapp.example.de:443/context/sublink

This is incorrect and shouldn't work in any browser. You are explicitly telling the browser that it should use plaintext http protocol on port 443. If your server is serving SSL on that port, the connection should fail (as it correctly does in Firefox).

Comment: thx for the feedback. Turned out it was a false parameter in our default spring security configuration that added :443 to every link.